# How to use preg_replace to add "www" and "http://" in a URL missing these substrings?

Tags: php

I want to make this by the `preg_replace`:

```
$web = 'example.com';
```

I want the preg_replace make it `http://www.example.com` and if it `http://example.com` no problem. It should add `http://` in it found in the URL.

I want do that is `http://` not exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
preg_replace("/^(?:http:\/\/)?(.*)/","http://$1",$web);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regular expressions for that. Just do `$web = "http://$web"`.

Comment: The code has it is reported would add http:// even when it is already present. I agree there is no need to use regular expressions, in such cases.

Answer (score 1):

```
if( 0 !== strpos( $web, 'http://' ) )
{
    $web = 'http://'.$web;
}
```

Basically, you don't need a regular expression. What that should do is check to see if 'http://' is the first part of `$web`. If not, it will add 'http://' to the beginning of the string. Otherwise, it does nothing.

Another way to do that is to simply check if it's false... `if( false === strpos( $web, 'http://' ) )` That should execute if the function fails. I don't think that's the best way to do it, however.

Comment: Rather than using `strstr()`, it would be better to use `strpos()`.

Comment: @kiamlaluno - Thanks, I always forget about `strpos()`. Updated my answer to include that instead.